# Could not set BinaryResponseListener output on device

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I got vectornav vn200, and I have followed exactly this tutorial : https://github.com/dawonn/vectornav When I write "roslaunch vectornav vn200.launch", I get an error:

```
quuser@quuser:~$ roslaunch vectornav vn200.launch
... logging to /home/quuser/.ros/log/17a60ad4-767d-11e6-9325-6c88140d9b00/roslaunch-quuser-3421.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://quuser:40251/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20
 * /vectornav/async_output_rate: 100
 * /vectornav/async_output_type: 0
 * /vectornav/binary_data_output_port: 2
 * /vectornav/binary_gps_data_output_rate: 4
 * /vectornav/binary_imu_data_output_rate: 100
 * /vectornav/binary_ins_data_output_rate: 20
 * /vectornav/gps/frame_id: LLA
 * /vectornav/imu/frame_id: LLA
 * /vectornav/serial_baud: 115200
 * /vectornav/serial_port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    vectornav (vectornav/vn200_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[vectornav-1]: started with pid [3440]
[ INFO] [1473419170.342982098]: Initializing vn200. Port:/dev/ttyUSB0 Baud:115200

[ INFO] [1473419170.370371743]: About to set SynchronizationControl
[ INFO] [1473419170.380570872]: Set SynchronizationControl
[FATAL] [1473419175.451857938]: Could not set BinaryResponseListener output on device via: /dev/ttyUSB0, Error Text: Unknown Error
[vectornav-1] process has died [pid 3440, exit code 1, cmd /home/quuser/catkin_ws/devel/lib/vectornav/vn200_node __name:=vectornav __log:=/home/quuser/.ros/log/17a60ad4-767d-11e6-9325-6c88140d9b00/vectornav-1.log].
log file: /home/quuser/.ros/log/17a60ad4-767d-11e6-9325-6c88140d9b00/vectornav-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
quuser@quuser:~$
```

Error i saying

```
Could not set BinaryResponseListener output on device via: /dev/ttyUSB0, Error Text: Unknown Error
```

Here is my launch file content:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="vectornav" type="vn200_node" name="vectornav"  output="screen" > 
      
      <param name="serial_port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyUSB0" />
      <param name="serial_baud" type="int"    value="115200" />
      
      <param name="binary_data_output_port" type="int"    value="2" />
      <param name="binary_gps_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="4" />
      <param name="binary_ins_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="20" />
      <param name="binary_imu_data_output_rate" type="int"    value="100" />
      
      <!-- Type: 0 None (Polling method), 19 IMU, 20 GPS, 22 INS -->
      <param name="async_output_type" type="int"    value="0" />
      <param name="async_output_rate" type="int"    value="100" />
      
      <param name="imu/frame_id" type="string" value="LLA" />
      <param name="gps/frame_id" type="string" value="LLA" />
    </node> 
    
</launch>
```

Before it was connected to `/dev/ttyTHS0`, I was getting error `ls: cannot access /dev/ttyTHS0: No such file or directory`, however i changed it to `dev/ttyUSB0` and it is fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243443/could-not-set-binaryresponselistener-output-on-device/) by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the owner and group of `/dev/ttyUSB0`. and try `sudo chown quuser /dev/ttyUSB0`.

---

EDIT

You can use the `cutecom` which is a serial port monitor to open `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and read data from your device.

You can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install cutecom`.

If `cutecom` can read your data, then you can say that your device works fine and there is something wrong with your ROS node program or launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-09**:
first the owner was `dialout` and the after adding `quuser` :
crw-rw-rw- 1 quuser dialout 188, 0 سبت  9 14:06 /dev/ttyUSB0

but still, I am getting same error

```
[FATAL] [1473425315.697490491]: Could not set BinaryResponseListener output on device via: /dev/ttyUSB0, Error Text: Unknown Error
```

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-09**:
Yes, `cutecom` can read the data from Vectornav device and I am getting them properly.

So, what do you really suggest ?

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-09**:
I don't know the details, I think maybe your param in the launch file is not right, or maybe you have to debug your `vn200_node` program.

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-09**:
I am just a newbie, could you please let me know how to debug `vn200_node` file

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-10**:
you can use GDB or print some debug infomation. First of all you have to make sure `vn200_node` can open your device and get the data.

**Comment by [sn.badnawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27908/sn.badnawa/) on 2016-09-10**:
well, I checked content of my launch file, and as you said there were some problem with parameters, it was not matching with vn200_node.

Thank you for your kind help Shay : )